# How to write a test cases in this yaml file

Tags: node.js, azure, testing, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am having a issue to where exactly i need to add test cases task in yaml file becausei building the Nodejs code in Docker can i add test cases test in Dockerfile or should i can add task after the Docker is that ok..

please give us some ideas how it will work

Yaml file:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxxxxx9f-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
      imageRepository: 'jui-dev'
      webAppName: 'itdev'
  containerRegistry: 'jmrtvg.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: 
          $(tag)
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
        azureSubscription: JMsDe
        appType: 'webAppContainer'
        WebAppName: $(webAppName)
        DockerNamespace: 'jM.azurecr.io'
        DockerRepository: $(imageRepository)
        DockerImageTag: '$(tag)'
```

Docker File:

FROM node:20.8.1 as node
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

#Stage: 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/it-planning /usr/share/nginx/html

Some ideas how to write test cases in Docker file or yaml file

Comment: If the Docker image you're building is for the app that you're doing to deploy, then you should be running the tests as part of that build, so that the build fails when the tests do. I don't know anything about `npm`, but doesn't it have a way to run tests that are found in some default directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **run the Tests commands in the `Dockerfile` itself** then **build it and push it in Azure Container Registry** and **use it for your Azure Web App Deployment.**

**My Dockerfile:-**

```
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the entire app directory into the container
COPY . .

# Run tests (replace 'test' with your actual test command)
RUN npm test

# Build the React app for production
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port used by the React app
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the React app when the container starts
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Dockerfile you can try:-**

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM node:20.8.1 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Run tests
FROM node:20.8.1 as test
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install # Include test-specific dependencies if needed
RUN npm test # Run your test scripts here

# Stage 3: Finalize for production
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/it-planning /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**My Azure Devops YAML code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '256dd76d-688e-425b-9435-f9c25e5d9faa'
  imageRepository: 'myreactapp'
  containerRegistry: 'siliconacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

**Output:-**

[image]